# pdflatex subtitle in pdf changed after system update

Tags: pdftex

After updating many packages on my linux machine I encountered `2022` instead of `1950` on the pdf after running `pdflatex` on the the snippet below.
What can I do (except restoring my system)?

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,landscape,titlepage]{article}%
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}%
\usepackage{lmodern}%
\usepackage{textcomp}%
\usepackage{lastpage}%
\usepackage[a4paper,left=1cm,right=1cm,top=3cm,bottom=3cm,headheight=3em]{geometry}%
\usepackage{xcolor}%
\usepackage{graphicx}%
\usepackage[english]{babel}%
\usepackage{blindtext}%
\usepackage{xpatch}%
\usepackage{floatrow}%
\usepackage{caption}%
\usepackage{fancyhdr}%
\usepackage{titlesec}%
%
\xpretocmd{\section}{\thispagestyle{plain}}{}{}%
\pagecolor{darkgray}%
\pagecolor{white}%
\color{darkgray}%
\pagestyle{fancy}%
\title{Jane Doe}%
\author{Portfolio | 2022}%
\date{}%
\rhead{Jane Doe}%
\fancyhf{}%
\fancyhead{}%
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}%
\fancyhead[RO]{{Jane Doe}\\\vspace{0.5em}\underline{\leftmark}\\\vspace{0.05em}\rightmark}%
\renewcommand\sectionmark[1]{\markboth{#1}{\mysubtitle}}%
\titleclass{\section}{page}%
\assignpagestyle{\section}{empty}%
\titleformat{\section}[display]{\centering\Huge\bfseries}{\sectionname}{0pt}{\huge}[\clearpage]%
\newcommand{\subtitle}[1]{\gdef\mysubtitle{#1}\ignorespaces}%
\newcommand{\fakesection}[2]{\clearpage\sectionmark{#2}}%
%
\begin{document}%
\normalsize%
\maketitle%
\subtitle{2022}%
\fakesection*{Foo}%
\pagebreak%
\begin{figure}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}%
\end{figure}%
\pagebreak%
\begin{figure}%
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=8cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]{\caption*{lorem ipsum}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}%
\end{figure}%
\pagebreak%
\subtitle{1950}%
\fakesection*{Bar}%
\pagebreak%
\begin{figure}%
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}%
\end{figure}%
\pagebreak%
\begin{figure}%
\floatbox[{\capbeside\thisfloatsetup{capbesideposition={right,top},capbesidewidth=8cm}}]{figure}[\FBwidth]{\caption*{lorem ipsum}}{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}%
\end{figure}%
\pagebreak%
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: why are you using figure everywhere instead of simply inserting the graphics?

Comment: I honestly don't know

Comment: Could this be the stem of my problem?

Comment: yes, you are creating float pages and marks works differently there.

Comment: Given the **necessity of float pages** and the arise of the problem **after updating**: Do you have any idea where I should start digging?

Comment: I haven't really investigated. Your example is too long and loads too many package. Also I can't reproduce your claim that the problem is new, I get it in texlive 2019 too but imho your main problem is that `\subtitle{2022}%
\fakesection*{Foo}` doesn't print anything and so doesn't trigger a shipout to update the marks and that makes the state a bit unclear when the float page is created.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer `\subtitle{2022}% \fakesection*{Foo}` **are printed** on the upper right corner. The command `fakesection*` is defined at the beginning of the script. It's purpose --opposed to `section*`-- is to have the upper right information **but without** adding an additional title page between each section.

Comment: they do not print something. `\fakesection` is defined as `{\clearpage\sectionmark{#2}}` which means that it only issues a `\mark` command. `\subtitle` is defined as `{\gdef\mysubtitle{#1}\ignorespaces}` and so has no output either. A document containing only these commands would produce no output, try it out. You are relying on later material to create pages and then to pick up the marks correctly.

Answer (score 2):

I can not confirm your claim that it worked previously, but as your real document probably doesn't use example-image, one can assume that your example doesn't replicate everything.

In any case your example can be pulled down to this:

```
\documentclass{article}%
\makeatletter
\def\@oddhead{\leftmark, \rightmark \hfil\thepage}%
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\showoutput
\markboth{Foo}{2022}

\begin{figure}
 yyy 
\end{figure}

\clearpage
xxx \markboth{Bar}{1950}

\newpage
xxx 

\end{document}
```

If you look in the log, you can see that the first `\markboth` is not executed on the first page as this page contains only a float which is handled first (and independently from the rest of material on the page), but that all marks are output on the second page:

```
Completed box being shipped out [2]
.....
....
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 539.94232fil
...\write-{}
...\marks1{Foo}
...\marks2{2022}
...\marks3{2022}
...\mark{{Foo}{2022}}   %<-----first mark
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 5.69446
...\hbox(4.30554+0.0)x345.0, glue set 310.83327fil
....\hbox(0.0+0.0)x15.0
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
....\OT1/cmr/m/n/10 x
....\glue 3.33333 plus 1.66666 minus 1.11111
....\penalty 10000
....\glue(\parfillskip) 0.0 plus 1.0fil
....\glue(\rightskip) 0.0
...\marks1{Bar}
...\marks2{1950}
...\marks3{1950}
...\mark{{Bar}{1950}} %<----- second mark
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

Therefore the header of the second page shows as `\rightmark` ("the first right mark") `2022`, and as `\leftmark` ("the last left mark"), `Bar`.

This behaviour is not new, and if you want to avoid that your mark ends up on the wrong page, ensure that your mark commands are tied to something that is really output on the page, and don't create documents consisting only of floats.

Comment: Thank you. How can I reproduce your example with an example image? Adding `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}` after the first begin figure, throws an unfinished sequence error.

Comment: load the graphicx package.

Comment: Thank you. Is it my correct understanding, that your provided script example replicates the problem in a shortened form but does not contain the solution?

Comment: no the solution is in the text: "tie the mark command to text printed on the page".

Comment: I need `Bar 1950` printed. Can you please show me how that can be accomplished?

Comment: remove the figure environments. Then it should work.

Answer (score 0):

Bad layout many pagebreak that causes error to call the display try to load the figure each by one then next to typeset the figures.

Try to use another correct usepackage to call the location of the file.

And also do not fit in the figures inside the 2 subtitle, just put it out the instead use wrapfigure.

Comment: Welcome to TSE. This seems to be a comment rather than an answer.